# await Async function with selenium Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating a small program to return the name of all the link titles when you search for something on google using selenium

here's the code:

```
const {Builder,By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();

var search_query='tigers';

(async()=>{

await driver.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search_query}`);

await driver.findElements(By.css('h3')).then((search_results)=>{ 
 for (var i = 0; i < search_results.length; i++)
  search_results[i].getText().then((text)=>{console.log(text);})
});

console.log('...Task Complete!')
})();
```

and when you run it the output is as follows:-

> ```
> ...Task Complete!
> Tiger - Wikipedia
> Top stories
> Tigers (2014 film) - Wikipedia
> Detroit Tigers (@tigers) · Twitter
> Tiger | Species | WWF
> Videos
> Official Detroit Tigers Website | MLB.com
> Tiger | WWF
> Tiger - National Geographic Kids
> Tiger guide: species facts, how they hunt and where to see in ...
> Related searches
> Images
> Description
> ```

Clearly the `...Task Complete!` should be logged after the entire function is completed

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong I've used the appropriate `await` keywords to keep the flow of code orderly, is the error in `then()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `.then(()=>...)` doesn't return a Promise, the `await` keyword at the beginning does nothing. Node has started the Promises of getting the h3's, getting their text content, and logging them, but your misplaced `await` doesn't tell Node to wait for all that to finish. You'll want to `await` getting the elements, then synchronously loop through all the elements, `await`ing the text, then synchronously print the text, and finally synchronously print `"...Task Complete!"`

```js
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();

const search_query = 'tigers';

(async () => {
    await driver.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search_query}`);

    const h3Elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('h3'));
    for (const h3 of h3Elements) {
        const text = await h3.getText();
        console.log(text);
    }

    console.log('...Task Complete!')
})();
```

If you wanted to reduce extra variables, you can do this instead:

```js
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();

const search_query = 'tigers';

(async () => {
    await driver.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search_query}`);

    const h3Elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('h3'));
    for (const h3 of h3Elements) {
        console.log(await h3.getText());
    }

    console.log('...Task Complete!')
})();
```

Comment: the first code you sent works thank you so much!
 but the second reduced variables one doesn't work it shows `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in the line `console.log(await h3.getText());` maybe the issue is with using `await` in the console log when `(h3)=>` is not a async function?

Comment: @cakelover I've updated the solution for the reduced variables version, please check now

Comment: well it's not showing any error during compilation but it gives the same wrong output as asked in the question

Comment: Yeah, since that wasn't a top-level `await`, it was causing problems. You could solve that with `Promise.all` and `.map` but that just clutters things up. I've updated the 2nd part, which just removes an unnecessary variable (`text`), which works since it's in the top-level context for `await`