# Why is my Selenium scraper returning the same image source for different queries?

Tags: node.js, express, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the following Google Images scraper set up on an Express server. It takes an array of queries and is supposed to return an array of each query's first image result's `src` value, i.e. a separate Google Image search for each query.

```
let queryArr = ['cat', 'dog', 'cheeta', 'boy', 'girl', 'lion']

let driver = undefined;
const startSelenium = async () => {
  const options = new Options();
  options.addArguments('--headless')
  options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
  options.addArguments('--incognito')
  driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();
}

const Scrape = async (queryArr) => {

  if (!driver) {
    await startSelenium();
  }

  try {
    let imgSources = [];
    for (const query of queryArr) {
      const url = `https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1873&bih=990&q=${query}`;
      await driver.get(url);
      const img = await driver.findElement(By.className('Q4LuWd'));
      const imgSrc = await img.getAttribute('src');
      imgSources.push(imgSrc);
    }
    return imgSources;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Scrape() error: \n${e}`);
  }
};
```

This basic logic works fine for single searches, but when passed an array of queries like this it returns the `src` of the first query six times. I've tried several different methods involving `sleep()`, `until`, etc. but am having no luck. How can I fix this?

Also, is there a way to do this concurrently to speed it up? I had `Promise.all()` set up on the client side but the returned array was wrong as explained above, so I thought I'd try to do it on the backend.

Comment: I believe the issue is with `await` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927085/await-async-function-with-selenium-nodejs

Comment: @AndrewRyan  Isn't it always lol?? It turns out it was an async issue with `imgSources.push(imgSrc)`. Thanks for the feeback.

Answer (score 0):

Always an async issue. I got it working by pushing to the array asynchronously as well.

```
...
let imgSources = [];
for (const query of queryArr) {
    const url = `https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1873&bih=990&q=${query}`;
    await driver.get(url);
    const img = await driver.findElement(By.className('Q4LuWd'));
    const imgSrc = await img.getAttribute('src');
    (async () => imgSources.push(imgSrc))();
}
...
```